# Identify people by recognizing their entire bodies

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

we're working on project where people try to find photos of themselves from large albums. Inorder to make their job easy, we used AWS Rekognition for facial recognition and automatically suggesting photos to the user.

But most of our photos are candid and natural, like sports photos, graduations, parties, etc.. so the face is not clear most of the time. So AWS Search Faces did not work very well.

Are there solutions / models / algorithms that take into account the entire body of a person and identify them from a large set of photos?

I'm a Machine Learning newbie and I came across these papers - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.06890.pdf and https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.09967

Struggling to make sense of how to implement them for the project.

Looking for some pointers. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm afraid that your question may be too broad. Where exactly are you stuck?